# Finding the critical value of bifurcation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, bifurcation

I want to find the critical value/bifurcation value, $a_c$, I'm not sure if I'm approaching this the correct way.

$$ \dot{x} = x(1-x) - \frac{1}{4}(a+1)^2\left(\frac{x}{x+a}\right)$$

A previous example I did broke the function up into two separate pieces and then took the derivative to find $x$. Used the $x$ back into the original function to find a critical.

So I think how it should be done is as follows:

$$ d/dx (x -x^2) = -d/dx(\frac{1}{4}(a+1)^2(\frac{x}{x+a}))$$
$$ 1 -2x = -\frac{1}{4}(a+1)^2(a)$$
$$ x = \frac{1}{8}(a+1)^2a -1 $$

Then I would plug this x value into $\dot{x} = 0$ to solve for a-critical. Is this the correct approach? Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Shouldn't you be setting $x' = 0$ and solving for the values of $x$ to find critical points? This gives $$x= 0, x= \dfrac{1-a}{2}, x= \dfrac{1-a}{2}$$

Comment: @Moo No those would be the fixed points. I'm looking for the critical value of a which when you reach more fixed points are created/destroyed.

Comment: @Safder What Moo said is correct. Once you have found the critical points (which Moo did for you), you evaluate your Jacobian at those critical points and determine what values of $a$ cause a change in stability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equilibrium points $x^* \in \lbrace{0, \tfrac{1}{2}(1-a)}\rbrace$ are obtained by solving $\dot x = f(x) = 0$ with respect to $x$, where
$$
f(x) = \frac{-x}{x+a}\left(\frac{1-a}{2} - x\right)^2 .
$$
The local stability of the equilibrium points can be investigated by examining the sign of the derivative
$$
f'(x) = \frac{2 x^2 + 3 a x - a\frac{1-a}{2}}{(x + a)^2} \left(\frac{1 - a}{2} - x\right) .
$$
The derivative takes the following particular values $f'(0) = -\frac{1}{4a}(1-a)^2$  and $f'\big(\tfrac{1}{2}(1-a)\big) = 0$
at the equilibrium points $x^*$. Hence, $x^*=0$ is either unstable or asymptotically stable. The equilibrium $x^*=\tfrac{1}{2}(1-a)$ is hyperbolic, which requires to examine the variations of $f'$ in its vicinity.

For $a<0$, $x^* = 0$ is unstable.

- Case $a<-1$. The equilibrium $x^* = \tfrac{1}{2}(1-a)$ is semi-stable (asymptotically left-stable).
- Case $a=-1$. The equilibrium $x^* = \tfrac{1}{2}(1-a)$ is asymptotically stable.
- Case $-1< a< 0$. The equilibrium $x^* = \tfrac{1}{2}(1-a)$ is semi-stable (asymptotically right-stable).

For $a=0$, there is only one equilibrium $x^* = \tfrac{1}{2}(1-a)$ which is semi-stable (asymptotically right-stable).

For $a>0$, $x^* = 0$ is asymptotically stable.

- Case $0< a< 1$. The function $f$ is decreasing to the right of the equilibrium point $x^* = \tfrac{1}{2}(1-a)$ ($f$ has a local maximum). Hence, the equilibrium is semi-stable (asymptotically right-stable).
- Case $a = 1$. Both equilibria merge together, and they are asymptotically stable.
- Case $a > 1$. The function $f$ is decreasing to the left of the equilibrium point $x^* = \tfrac{1}{2}(1-a)$ ($f$ has a local minimum). Hence, the equilibrium is semi-stable (asymptotically left-stable).

If the study is restricted to positive $a$, a bifurcation occurs at $a=1=a_c$.

Comment: I dont want to waste those bounty points and I would rather give it to you since you help me so much understanding PDE!